# How to fit Rayleigh PDF curve to a set of data?

Tags: regression, modeling

I have a set of a data that I acquired through a graph digitizer. It follows the contour of a piece of glassware and I would like to produce a function to fit the dataset. I have noticed that the function looks quite similar to the probability density function of a Rayleigh distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution). The function is equal to $xe^{-x^2}$. How would I go about fitting the dataset I have to this function? Here is a link to the data: [https://plotly.com/~ashok_a/1/](https://plotly.com/%7Eashok_a/1/)

Comment: If you joint to your question a numerical example of dataset one could show how to proceed for the fitting.

Comment: The coordinates of the points n° 20 to 30 are missing.

Comment: @JJacquelin I believe you get all the data if you click to "export" in upper right corner of the Data page.

Comment: OK. I got it. See my answer.

Comment: This is not a good formulation of your problem, because the functional form will vary with orientation, making the problem ill-posed.  Indeed, because your last three points have the same $x$ coordinate but differing $y$ coordinate, you are *doomed* to fail.  (Complex glassware cannot be depicted as a graph $(x,f(x))$ no matter how it might be oriented.)  You need instead to fit a *parametric function* $(x(t), y(t))$ or an *implicit function* determined by $f(x,y)=0.$  Could you explain what you hope to accomplish by making such a fit?

Comment: For an alternative approach that does not impose some preconceived functional form on the fit, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24929/664.  It includes working `R` code and applies correctly even to closed contours (which can never be represented as graphs of a real-valued function).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the shape of the data it is obvious that the probability density function of a Rayleigh distribution is not a convenient model. This function tends smoothly to zero for $x$ tending to infinity which is far to be the case of the data which shows an abrupt deacrease around $x=37.$ It should be wasting time to use the Rayleigh model for a bad result.

The best should be to look for a better physical model.

In abscence of a convenient physical model one must be content with a purely mathematical model. One can try many kind of functions. For example a polynomial fraction might be a good candidat :
$$y(x)=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x-d}$$
They are a lot of softwares for non-linear regression. Any one will give a result such as :

[image]

The fitting is still not very good. Of course much better fit can be obtained with polynomial fractions made of polynomials of higher degrees.